# Why isn't my overloading < operator not working for STL sort

Tags: c++, stl, operator-overloading

I have this following code where I want to sort vector of string according to the last character of the string. I've done the following but the sorting is done by default rules.

Here's the overloading < part:

```
bool operator<(const string &s1, const string &s2){
    return s1.at(s1.size() - 1) < s2.at(s2.size() - 1);
}
```

This is in main:

```
vector <string> nameList;
int n;
cin>>n;
while(n--){
    string name;
    char str[100];
    cin>>str;
    name += str;
    nameList.push_back(name);
}

sort(nameList.begin(), nameList.end());
for(int i = 0; i < nameList.size(); i++)
    cout<<nameList.at(i)<<endl;
```

Code in ideone: [LINK](http://ideone.com/OzCeV1)

Comment: Are you sure it is being called? Your `operator<` that is?

Comment: The string class [already have a full set of comparison operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp). Instead you might want to use the [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) function where you provide your own predicate (and name it something more appropriate instead).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks! It's working now by using a function with std::sort [New Code IDEONE](http://ideone.com/OzCeV1).

Comment: @Niall But why isn't it working this way. why not called??

Comment: @sud6 because inside `std::sort` the first overload that gets found is the existing one in namespace `std`, so your overload is never found and never used

Comment: @sud6, It is not in the `std` namespace. And `std` already has an overload for the string `operator<`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted, your `operator<` is not being called, `std::string` already has overloaded operators in the `std` namespace.

There are two versions of [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort), one that will use `operator<` and another that takes a custom predicate to sort the container.
Add a custom predicate, you can still used `sort` to sort your `vector` as required;

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

bool lastchar(const string &s1, const string &s2){
    return s1.at(s1.size() - 1) < s2.at(s2.size() - 1);
}

int main(){
        vector <string> nameList;
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        while(n--){
            string name;
            char str[100];
            cin>>str;
            name += str;
            nameList.push_back(name);
        }

        sort(nameList.begin(), nameList.end(), &lastchar);
        for(int i = 0; i < nameList.size(); i++)
            cout<<endl<<nameList.at(i);

        return 0;
}
```

I've called it `lastchar`, but you can name it what ever is best. As an added bonus, if you can used C++11 or above, you can make the predicate a lambda.

```
sort(nameList.begin(), nameList.end(), [] (const string &s1, const string &s2){
  return s1.at(s1.size() - 1) < s2.at(s2.size() - 1);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not being used, you have to pass it into `std::sort` - something like:

```
sort(nameList.begin(), nameList.end(), [](const string &s1, const string &s2) {
    return s1.at(s1.size() - 1) < s2.at(s2.size() - 1);
}
```