# Can I disable copy construction of a class based on the properties of it's template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, constructor, metaprogramming

A variant is the obvious example for this:

```
template <typename... Ts>
class variant {
  using types = meta::list<Ts...>;

  variant() = default;

  template <typename = std::enable_if_t<
    meta::all_of<types, meta::quote<std::is_copy_constructible>>{}
  >
  variant(const variant &);
};
```

Using [Meta](https://github.com/ericniebler/meta) to remove TMP boilerplate code around checking to see if all of a parameter pack fulfil a trait.

I know this isn't correct as the copy constructor [can't be templated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19167355/649140) amongst other restrictions. Is this something that is possible to do in a different manner? C++14+ should be fine as I'm using GCC 4.9 and Clang 3.5.

Comment: Use a `static_assert` in the copy-constructor

Comment: @0x499602D2 That causes `is_copy_constructible` to lie.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/27073082/3647361 ?

Comment: @Columbo Yes. Closed about 10 seconds before your comment. :)

Comment: ah, my bad! i sucked at searching

Comment: I've just added another answer to the duped question, check it out. I think it works better than others.