# Overloads involving forwarding references in interfaces

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, unique-ptr

I am currently writing a library, which facilitates deferred calls and registration of callbacks, which must work using gcc, clang and MSVC.

I have encountered something that I find very strange. I have a function with two overloads and I get an error if and only if, the function is defined in the interface. I get the same error using gcc 6.3.0-18 and clang 3.8.1-24.

Create an interface following the recommendation by Google with a protected constructor.

```
#include <queue>
#include <memory>

template <class T>
class IA {
 public:
  virtual ~IA() = default;
  // virtual bool push(const T& souce) = 0; /* Issue */
  virtual bool push(T&& source) = 0;
 protected:
  IA() = default;
};
```

A class implementing the interface

```
template <class T>
class A : public IA<T> {
 public:
  ~A() override {};

  bool push(const T& source) {
    m_queue.push(source);
    return true;
  }

  bool push(T&& source) {
    m_queue.push(std::move(source));
    return true;
  }
 private:
  std::queue<T> m_queue;
};
```

Now, if I instantiate the class using a `std::unique_ptr`,

```
int main() {
  A<std::unique_ptr<float> > a;
  return 0;
}
```

Everything works fine. Unless, I uncomment the function with prototype `bool push(const T& soruce)` from the interface. Then, I get the error.

```
/usr/include/c++/6/ext/new_allocator.h:120:4: error: use of deleted 
function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const 
std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = float; _Dp = 
std::default_delete<float>]’
{ ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
```

I am fully aware of the fact that `std::unique_ptr`'s cannot be copied, but why is the error not appearing if the function is present only in the implementation.

Comment: I think the problem is related with the copy constructor, unique_ptr does allow a copy constructor or assigment.

Comment: I know that. The strange thing is that the error disappear if I remove the function from the interface. Everything still works. The reason why I want to keep the overload is for backwards compatibility

Comment: Well. After experimenting a bit, I think the problem is when the template function is evaluated by the compiler. In the case when the line is not commented, the template member function is evaluated when the object is created, so the error shows when you declare an object. But when the copy function member is not in code, the member function is evaluated when it is used.

Comment: You may be right, but I still find it a bit strange, why it works if I remove the declaration in the interface. I found I neat way to get around the issue using `std::enable_if`

Comment: I have used the procedure found here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27073082/conditionally-disabling-a-copy-constructor

Comment: This code does NOT contain any universal references.  `T&&` is only a forward reference / universal reference if `T` is a parameter of the function template, but here it's a parameter of the class template.

Comment: @aschepler You are right, my bad

Answer (score 3):

The compiler only complains about this when you instantiate a template with a non-copyable type like `std::unique_ptr<T>`. The way template resolution works in C++ is through a process called [monomorphization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189604/what-is-monomorphisation-with-context-to-c). The compiler creates distinct types for each template instance. `A<int>` and `A<float>` are unrelated after monomorphization is completed. On the other hand, this means that the compiler only creates these instances for the types you actually use.

In your particular case, it will just compile fine as long as you don't use a noncopyable type for `T`, or if you use one and uncomment the code that calls its copy constructor - `bool push(const T& source)`.

In addition to that, it seems like compilers don't even compile the first push method when they are able to infer that it is unused ([see live example](https://godbolt.org/g/u9qoPJ)). This means that it can contain parseable, but incorrect C++ code. If the method is virtual, compilers can no longer infer that it's not used (as they could be called via a vtable), so it has to generate code for the method and thus encounters the error.

Comment: The source compiles even when I use a non-copyable type, e.g. `std::unique_ptr<float>` and keep the function `bool push(const T& source)` in the implementation. That's what I find strange. I have made a work-around using `std::enable_if` and `is_copy_constructible`.

Comment: Hmm. That is a surprise to me.... I solved my issue by adding another template argument `bool = std::is_copy_constructible` for both interface and implementations. Thanks again. It demonstrates why even for templates, it makes sense to define an interface...

Comment: It also demonstrates the performance costs of doing so - redundant generated code at compile time and the vtable lookup at runtime. Thanks for the question anyway, I learned something!